# javascript not being enqueued correctly

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

I have the following in my child theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'ors_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style' );
function enqueue_parent_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('ors-animations', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/javascripts/animations.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
```

The child theme is active, however, the file `www.example.com/wp-content/themes/child-theme/javascripts/animations.js` is not being enqueued.

Help appreciated.

Comment: `ors_enqueue_scripts` action hook? Where is it defined? Normally enqueuing is done inside `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

Comment: Are the other styles enqueued?

Comment: Yes they are @bravokeyl.

Comment: What about my other question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have typo in your code:
ors_enqueue_scripts should be wp_enqueue_scripts

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',   'enqueue_parent_theme_style' );
function enqueue_parent_theme_style()
{
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' ); 
wp_enqueue_script('ors-animations', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/javascripts/animations.js', array( 'jquery' )); 
}
```